# What will be the best to parse x264 bitstream for extracting motion vectors information?

Tags: video-encoding, x264

What will be the best way to parse x264 bitstream for extracting motion vectors information?

Comment: The post was "What will be the best to parse x264 bitstream for extracting motion vectors information?" The best what? API? Command line utility? GUI application? On Windows?

Answer (score 0):

get a JM, find the place where the MV are being read from the bitstream, add the predictors and there you go.

Answer (score 0):

I'm look for this too.  Someone wrote an example. 
http://victor.csie.org/blog/archives/362

Probably not **the best**, at least it works.